# Cannot rename the file with the android app that I created

Tags: android, android-file

So I am creating an app that can select a pdf file and I want to rename that selected file with the input that user will put in the Edittext.

Here is the code I am currently using for it but nothing happens when I click on the rename_the_file button. (I tried to log the process but no luck on that too)

```
sel_a_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                    .setType("application/pdf")
                    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 123);
            //To avoid using the rename_button when file is not selected
            rename_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String new_name = new_file_name.getText().toString();
                    File f1 = new File(String.valueOf(selectedfile), String.valueOf(file_name));
                    File f2 = new File(String.valueOf(selectedfile), String.valueOf(new_name));
                    f1.renameTo(f2);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

and here is the onActivityResult and the method that I created to show the selected file name to a textview.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        selectedfile = data.getData(); //The uri with the location of the file
        file_name.setText(getFileName(selectedfile));
    }
}

private String getFileName(Uri selectedfile) {
    String path = selectedfile.getPath();
    String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    String file;
    if (filename.indexOf(".") > 0) {
        file = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."));
    } else {
        file = filename;
    }
    return file;
}
```

I have tried the following things to change the selected file name but no luck so far :

1)

```
String new_name = new_file_name.getText().toString();
File f1 = new File(String.valueOf(file_name));
File f2 = new File(String.valueOf(new_name));
f1.renameTo(f2);
```

2. 

```
String new_name = new_file_name.getText().toString();
File f1 = new File(String.valueOf(selectedfile));
File f2 = new File(String.valueOf(new_name));
f1.renameTo(f2);
```

3. 

```
String new_name = new_file_name.getText().toString();
File f1 = new File(String.valueOf(selectedfile), String.valueOf(file_name));
File f2 = new File(String.valueOf(selectedfile), String.valueOf(new_name));
f1.renameTo(f2);
```

I did tried this code that shows the toast if the rename happened or not.

```
String new_name = new_file_name.getText().toString();
File new_file = new File(selectedfileDirectory, new_name);
boolean b = selectedfile.renameTo(new_file);
if(b){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File renamed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nothing happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and the toast shows : nothing happened.

Comment: What's your target and compile version?

Comment: Please do not use both ACTION_PICK and ACTION_GET_CONTENT in one intent. Confusing.

Comment: @blackapps I don't know what to use then. I only know that ACTION_GET_Content brings that window to select a file

Comment: Check your file is exist before renaming it and also make sure whether it's not because of scoped storage related issue.

Comment: File exist confirm since I am selecting the file first before trying to renaming it. and since it's in my SD card (I tried internal storage one too) I add that user-permission too

Comment: `I don't know what to use then` Use only one. Not both. I see two actions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `data.getData()` for the `File` class as it is no file system path but a content scheme uri.

See for yourself that `data.getData().toString()` is a content scheme.

Comment: but if I use the selectedfile with String.valueof despite of being data.getData() it should work?

Comment: You cannot use data.getData() with the File class i told you. But anyhow .. which value do you get with valueof ? Compare with that content scheme.

Comment: I get the location of the file that I select

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
//Class variables
File selectedFile;
String selectedFileDirectory;
...
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    String uriString = uri.toString();
    selectedFile = new File(uriString);
    selectedFileDirectory = selectedFile.getParent();
  }
}
```

Then

```
rename_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String new_name = new_file_name.getText().toString();
                File newFile = new File(selectedFileDirectory, new_name);
                selectedFile.renameTo(f2);

            }
        });
```

Comment: I did edit my code and tried your code in it and put a toast for it also. but the toast says nothing happened (refer this above edited code)

Comment: Where do you want to write the new file after renaming it? External storage?